# is it necessary to clear the timeout variable each time

Tags: javascript, settimeout

In my application,I use many setTimeout function,so I am afraid if it will cause peformance problem:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // do something
},0);
```

And I found people use this manner:

```
var t=setTimeout(function(){
  // do something
  clearTimeout(t);
});
```

I wonder if it is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, object will be destroyed automatically (at least should be). You need to call `clearTimeout` when you need to remove already set timeout.

Ex: you have set timeout to 5 seconds on hovering some element but user moves out cursor from element before timeout elapsed - so you need to remove already initialized timeout.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not necessary. Use `clearTimeout()` to un-schedule a timeout that's still in the future (i.e. to *prevent* it from happening).

Clearing a timeout *after* it has happened (or while it is happening) has no positive effect.

This will suffice.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // do something
},0);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. The variable is only needed if you need to cancel the timeout before it happens. Calling `clearTimeout` from inside the callback has no effect, as there is no longer a timeout to stop.

Answer (score 1):

only if you want to cancel it before it happens - which you'll never be able to stop with a delay of 0...